# Android TextView Gravity is not being set programatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

I'm trying to add a `TextView` to a `LinearLayout` this way:

```
private TextView getNeededTextView(MyClass acc)
{
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setText(acc.getAccesabiltyString());
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    return tv;
}
```

and on the outside: `linearLayoutVar.addView(getNeededTextView(myClassVar));`

The text view is being added with its text, with the top margin but not with the gravity. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gravity attribute specifies the gravity of the view inside the bounds. You can check the difference between your code and the same changing this line

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

for this other

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

I think the attribute you're looking for is [Layout Gravity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) which specifies where, in a parent layout, a view should be placed

Comment: That helped thank you. I just didn't understand why it helped. When I add a textview in the xml I set it as WRAP_CONTENT so why did I need to add it now as MATCH_PARENT?

Comment: Oh, you don't. It was just an example so you can see how the `gravity` attribute works. Add your view with the `WRAP_CONTENT` value and, instead of settig its `gravity` value, set the `layout_gravity` value of its `LayoutParams`

Comment: I didn't understand.. I switched to MATCH_PARENT and it worked with doing the tv.setGravity.. still didn't understand why it worked

Comment: Enable `Show layout bounds` at developer options and you will see the difference between setting the size to `MATH_PARENT` and setting the `gravity` vs. setting the size to `WRAP_CONTENT` and setting the `layout_gravity`. Be aware that one thing is how it looks like and another totally different is how it is implemented